# I am making a programme which plays a typing game. When it moves onto the next line it doesn't add a space which is required otherwise cant continue

Tags: python, python-tesseract

This is what I currently have. I have also tried other options from what I have found but they all result in the same thing when moving onto the next line.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import pyautogui
import pytesseract 
import time
from PIL import Image

colour = 12, 79, 150

time.sleep(3)

ssl = True
while True:
    
    ss = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (535, 475, 1000, 110))
    if ss.getpixel == colour:
        True
    elif ss.getpixel != colour:
              
        ss.save(r"C:\Users\there\OneDrive\Desktop\VS Code\TypeRacer\screenshot\ss.png")
        print("saved")

        keyboard = Controller()

        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\Tesseract.exe"

        img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\there\OneDrive\Desktop\VS Code\TypeRacer\screenshot\ss.png")
        print("image opened")

        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
        print("image is stringPaY")

        text = text.replace("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, (, ), |, /, \, [, ], ',", "")
        text = text.replace("T", "T")
        text = text.replace("W", "W")
        print("done replacing")

        x = text.split(" ")
        x = " ".join(x)
        
        typing = True
        while typing:
                
            for chars in x:
                pyautogui.write(chars)
                
            colour2 = 209, 131, 131
            ss2 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (535, 475, 1000, 110))

            if ss2.getpixel == colour2:
                typing = False
                
            else:
                pass

    quit()
```

It works fine when it stay on one line, however it doesn't add the space on the final word of the line before it moves onto the next word.

[here is an image of what I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZhga.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you hoover the mouse over a tag, or clikc on it, you can read the usage of it. In your case, `typing` is _For questions related to data types. Do not use this tag for questions related to the physical act of typing on a keyboard._

Comment: Did you try [changing the page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) or adding a border to the image?